# Why aren't static final variables given default values?

Tags: java

Why aren't static final variables given default values, whereas static (but non-final variables are given default values).

What is the reason that such behavior was implemented in Java?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My bad, I dint look into his/her profile :)

Comment: Why is a question wrong on its face being voted up? (Genuinely curious.)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Because it's a good question, even though it's technically not *quite* right. Look how many people posted answers without questioning the basis of the question. Others will have a similar misunderstanding, and hopefully will come here and find Joni's answer and, like me, learn a little something they didn't used to know.

Comment: Not *quite* right?! A couple minutes and a few lines of code would have given lie to the underlying assumption--poorly researched.

Comment: @Dave: Well, we just disagree.

Comment: I doubt we disagree it was poorly researched, though.

Comment: Although I may be wrong, looks like.

Comment: I have added a comment to Joni Salonen's answer. Please look into it.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Seems just as well researched as 90% of the other questions here on SO. I'm just not seeing the problem (with the question) at all. But this is a largely pointless side conversation. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But they're not usually upvoted. There are two issues with the question, although depending on interpretation, there may only be one--it's either imprecise or wrong (or both), as your comment to the accepted answer implies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course static final variables are given default values, see for example this:

```
class Test {
    static final int x;
    static {
        printX();
        x = 42;
        printX();
    }

    static void printX() {
        System.out.println("Here x is "+x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

The output is:

```
Here x is 0
Here x is 42
```

If `x` wasn't given the default value of `0` as specified in [JLS 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), the output would depend on the JVM used. You might see some random number.

**Update**: Now that we have demonstrated that static final fields do get a default value, you may want to know why the default value is not enough. There is no good answer to that question, besides the obvious one: ["The spec says so"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2). Excerpt from 8.3.1.2:

> It is a compile-time error if a blank final (§4.12.4) class variable is not definitely assigned (§16.8) by a static initializer (§8.7) of the class in which it is declared.

We can only guess at the motivation behind such a restriction, but I think it's to make programs easier to understand. If you want to set the variable to 0 it's clearer to do it explicitly.

Comment: @Thomas small bug, fixed. The example was also missing a main method.

Comment: I love it when an answer just completely blows up the assumption everyone else (including me) makes. Nice one.

Comment: @JoniSalonen +1 you're totally right! I'm deleting my answer... (or voting for it anyway)

Comment: This might be a wrong answer. Just uncomment the line `x = 42`, and then try to compile the program.

Comment: @Vaibhav: It's almost a semantic point, what do you mean "default value." The variable **is** given a value prior the `x = 42;` line, so in that sense it has a default value; but you *have* to assign to it at some point, so in that sense it doesn't.

Comment: But if `x` was only **static (non-final)** , then there would not be any need for `x=42`, as it would get a default value. In this case, I think that no default value is given, that is why the compiler asks us to initialize the variable. Again ,that's just what I think.

Comment: @Vaibhav: Understood. I'm just saying, it depends a lot on how you look at it, because there is a default value there. You could even use that default value if you wanted, although you have to work at it: http://pastebin.com/kg95wq4M

Comment: @JoniSalonen, Now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Since they are `final`, you would not be able to modify them later, so the default value would also be, well, final. You would not be allowed to modify it later. Not very useful.

Comment: (I'm not, anymore--no machine on which to test.)