# The final data member gives different value (non-static data member)

Tags: java, final

Well the final concept says that if it is not assinged first then it gives the error in the  function in which it is called and also the final data member can also be assined from the constructors which is known as blank final concept..

But the final data member can not be changed once assigned but here

```
  public class Demo
  {
    final int w;

    public Demo()
    {

     fun();
     w=10;

    }

    public void fun()
    {

     System.out.println(w);

    }

    public static void main(String ... args)
    {

     Demo d=new Demo();
     System.out.println(d.w);

    }
  }
```

Here the in the fun() the value of w is 0..then i assign w as 10 so that in main println it is 10 now...

So my question is in fun() the w shows the value as 0 mean it's have a space in heap as a object and it's value is 0 which i already locked with final keyword so that it should not change further so why w=10 in the constructor not giving any error if the value of w already assgined which we can see in the fun()...and if the value of w can vary in constructor the why it's showing error when i assgined w=20 after w=10 in the constructor.?

and if the default value can be there for final variables then why it is a need to assign them explicitally..?

Answer (score 1):

ok from [When are static variables are initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-static-variables-are-initialized-in-java)

"What the compiler actually does is to internally produce a single class initialization routine that combines all the static variable initializers and all of the static initializer blocks of code, in the order that they appear in the class declaration. This single initialization procedure is run automatically, one time only, when the class is first loaded."

and from [Why aren't static final variables given default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381551/why-arent-static-final-variables-given-default-values)

"Now that we have demonstrated that static final fields do get a default value, you may want to know why the default value is not enough. There is no good answer to that question, besides the obvious one: "The spec says so". Excerpt from 8.3.1.2:

It is a compile-time error if a blank final (§4.12.4) class variable is not definitely assigned (§16.8) by a static initializer (§8.7) of the class in which it is declared.

We can only guess at the motivation behind such a restriction, but I think it's to make programs easier to understand. If you want to set the variable to 0 it's clearer to do it explicitly."

Answer (score 0):

```
final int w;
```

You have not yet initiliased it.

If you have

```
final int w=5;
```

Then it will show this compilatino error

```
The final field Demo.w cannot be assigned
```

Once you have defined the final value it cannot be assigned again.

Answer (score 0):

1. All fields are initialized to a default value. In your case, initially `w` gets set to `0`. That's why `System.out.println()` prints `0`.
2. All final fields must have been assigned a value by you at the end of the constructor. Only from *this* moment its value shouldn't change further.

Comment: the final non static variable can get only one time assignment in heap then if the value is being zero as default in the heap then it should not assigned again in the next line..

Comment: `w` is initialized to 0 by default as part of the initialization process. This happens to fields regardless of what you want to do with them. You're only assigning a value to `w` once, hence no error.

Comment: yes but w is not being initialized as 0 if it is final..you must explisitally have to assign it

Comment: yes but the program didn't give any error so why  it is running with both value of w as 0 and 10 if the w is final..?